# Nested loop results in same values for every column. Why?

Tags: r, loops, roc

The question is about nested for-loops. I know this is not always looked upon favorably always, but since this is a good way for me to learn how to use them I do use them for my project.

```
for (r in 1:R){
     for (p in 1:P){
MLR_obj = glm(outcomes[,r] ~ predictors[,1] + predictors[,2] + predictors[,3] + predictors[,4] +predictors[,5], family = "binomial")
       part_MLR = predict(MLR_obj, newdata = lst_aux_df[[p]], type = "response")
       AUCs[p,r] = roc(outcomes[,r], part_MLR, print.auc = TRUE)$auc
     }
 }
```

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] 
[1,] 0.8277432 0.8189622 0.7558232 0.7535461
[2,] 0.8277432 0.8189622 0.7558232 0.7535461
[3,] 0.8277432 0.8189622 0.7558232 0.7535461
[4,] 0.8277432 0.8189622 0.7558232 0.7535461
[5,] 0.8277432 0.8189622 0.7558232 0.7535461
```

These nested loops result in the same values for every row per column. I thought the loops above would take a different part_MLR for every iteration since I use a list of dataframes and pick one every iteration (lst_aux_df[[p]]). The dataframes are slightly different from each other on certain predictors. This is also kept in the lst_aux_df. So where does it go wrong? Why does column 1 have all the same values in row 1,2,3 etc.? Does the part_MLR not change?

Comment: Whenever I read a question along the lines of "why does my fore loop generate the same output on every iteration?", I think "lazy evaluation"...

Comment: Thank you, I had to read up on it. It could be the case, since during the browse() and debugging process it jumped straight to the top level after some "next" steps. Not entirely sure yet how to fix it, but it becomes somewhat more clear.